# Checkbox appear and disappear in Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently stuck on how should i change the current code to show if user selected Not Suit and it will show Movie and Drama checkbox or else if uncheck it disappear movie and drama checkbox and only showing Not Suit checkbox

my current code in Movie.kt

```
chkBoxNotsuit.setOnCheckedChangeListener { 
if (chkBoxNotsuit.isChecked == true) 
chkBoxMovie.isVisible = !isChecked 
chkBoxDrama.isVisible = !isChecked 
else 
chkBoxMovie.isInvisible = !notChecked 
chkBoxDrama.isInvisible = !notChecked 
displayToast(message)
}

fun displayToast(message:String){
    Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
chkBoxNotsuit.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
    chkBoxMovie.visibility = if (isChecked) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    chkBoxDrama.visibility = if (isChecked) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

Comment: may iask why does my toast is not woking and not showing like how the image shown

Comment: If you want to show the Toast, call 'displayToast(message) inside the callback

Comment: var chkboxType: String = "c"

  displayToast( "Not " + chkboxType)



chkBoxNotsuit.setOnCheckedChangeListener { checkBox, isChecked ->
            chkBoxMovie.isInvisible = !isChecked
            chkBoxDrama.isInvisible = !isChecked
            if (chkBoxNotsuitable.isChecked){
                chkboxType = "True"
            }
            else{
                chkboxType = "False"
            }

        }

Comment: i have try on this way is this a correct way of doing it ?

Comment: If you want to assign checkbox value to a var, you can do this directly:
chkboxType = isChecked.toString()

Answer (score 0):

```
chkBoxNotsuit=findViewById(R.id.chkBoxNotsuit)
linearLayout=findViewById(R.id.linearlayout)
chkBoxNotsuit.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        if(isChecked){
            linearLayout.isVisible=true       // Setting the checkboxes Visible
        }else{
            linearLayout.isVisible=false      // Setting the checkboxes Invisible
            displayToast(message)
            }
    }

}
fun displayToast(message:String){
    Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

}
```

In Movie.xml you also have to put android:visibility="invisible" as an attribute to linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are missing brackets for if/else. Never omit the the brackets unless you are doing a one-liner to assign to a variable, because it can lead to all kinds of bugs.
2. You are getting variable names mixed up. You used `isChecked` and `notChecked` inside your change listener. But how do you know if these values are up to date at the time when this listener will be called? You need to use the property of the actual checkbox to get the current value, or the value provided by the listener.
3. Your logic is excessively convoluted. You don't need to do `== true` when checking a Boolean. It is redundant, because a `==` check returns true or false, so it is like saying, if this is true, make it true. And you can avoid the whole if/else check to begin with by simply using the Boolean value to set your values.

Here is a simplified version of your code

```
chkBoxNotsuit.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
    chkBoxMovie.isVisible = !isChecked 
    chkBoxDrama.isVisible = !isChecked 
    displayToast(message)
}
```